# Is there a way to make Swiper only go one slide at the time?

Tags: swiper.js

I have full height horizontal swiper slide, I would like that when user swipes (mobile or touchpad) no matter how hard the swipe is, to scroll only to next/previous slide.

```
new Swiper('.swiper', {
  loop: false,
  speed: 700,
  grabCursor: false,
  mousewheel: true,
  slidesPerView: 'auto',
  spaceBetween: 0,
  freeMode: false,
});
```

here is a code pen [link](https://codepen.io/EntropyReversed/pen/NWLxRmm?editors=0110)
if you try to swipe hard using touchpad, it will skip multiple slides before stoping, I would like to make it scroll to next/prev.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the `shortSwipes`and `longSwipes` to `false` in your code like this:

```
new Swiper('.swiper', {
  loop: false,
  speed: 700,
  grabCursor: false,
  mousewheel: true,
  slidesPerView: 'auto',
  spaceBetween: 0,
  freeMode: false,
  shortSwipes: false,
  longSwipes: false
});
```

Comment: It still has the same behavior, If I swipe hard (touchpad) I end from slides 1 to 4.

Comment: Sadly, still the same, here is a [gif](https://imgur.com/a/woYkYZ0), here I only swipe once (on the laptop touchpad)

Comment: @Entropy did you fix this issue? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @milan-poudel did you find a solution to this problem? I have the same problem with Swiper 11.

Comment: @RogerBurkhard Actually there was a prop named thresholdtime or something in mousewheel prop..... <Swiper mousewheel={{thresholdTime:..... }} I increased this...... maybe swipe will be lil slow with this but it can work.

Answer (score 0):

Work at to me version 11:

freeMode: false,
shortSwipes: false,